# Undefined reference to symbol 'sem_post@@GLIBC_2.4

Tags: c, eclipse, linker

I am trying to build a sample code using Eclipse and ARM Sourcery Windows GCC C on Windows 8 machine. 
When I compile code : 
I get this error :

> Undefined reference to symbol 'sem_post@@GLIBC_2.4

The error doesn't say any line number or any location about the error, so I don't know which part of the code I should post.
How can I get rid of this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`sem_post()` lives in the pthread library, so make sure you use the `-pthread` flag when compiling and linking.

Comment: You have just saved a life. Was porting from Mac OS to a Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the -lpthread flag, when compiling solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

**gcc <filename.c> - o  -lpthread -lrt**